# Changing the display name of sender mail id through python script

Tags: python, smtplib

```
import smtplib
import os

EMAIL_ADDRESS = abc@gmail.com
EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()  #identifies ourselves with the mail server that we are using
    smtp.starttls() #to encrypt the traffic
    smtp.ehlo() #to re-identify ourselves as encrypted connection

    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)

    subject = "Regarding your text role"
    body = "This is to inform u that ur text role has been updated"

    msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

    smtp.sendmail('Random User <abc@gmail.com>','abcd@gmail.com', msg)
```

Even though code is getting successfully executed, I'm not getting the display name as 'Random User' in abcd@gmail.com
What may be the problem??

Comment: maybe Google Mail is too clever fot this trick.

Comment: You mean that I can't change the display name of Gmail id using the python script.@furas

Comment: different mailboxes may behave different. Some of them may not respect this name - all for your security so nobody can use fake name to steal your data (passwords or naked images). Others may use settings to display or not this name. Others may display it only if this mail is address book. So all depend on mailbox. And then you can't change it using Python and any other language. But I can't check how behave Gmail - so I can be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You don't wanna change the `from` in `smtp.sendmail()`, but you want to change the email content itself.

```
msg = 'From: Random User <abc@gmail.com>\nTo: abcd@gmail.com\nSubject: subject\n\nbody'
smtp.sendmail('abc@gmail.com','abcd@gmail.com', msg)
```